# Numpy error when converting array of ctypes types to void pointer

Tags: python, numpy, ctypes, ffi

I'd like to send a list of strings to a C function:

```
from ctypes import c_double, c_void_p, Structure, cast, c_char_p, c_size_t, POINTER
import numpy as np


class FFIArray(Structure):
    """
    Convert sequence of structs or types to C-compatible void array

    """

    _fields_ = [("data", c_void_p), ("len", c_size_t)]

    @classmethod
    def from_param(cls, seq):
        """  Allow implicit conversions """
        return seq if isinstance(seq, cls) else cls(seq)

    def __init__(self, seq, data_type):
        array = np.ctypeslib.as_array((data_type * len(seq))(*seq))
        self._buffer = array.data
        self.data = cast(array.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(data_type)), c_void_p)
        self.len = len(array)


class Coordinates(Structure):

    _fields_ = [("lat", c_double), ("lon", c_double)]

    def __str__(self):
        return "Latitude: {}, Longitude: {}".format(self.lat, self.lon)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tup = Coordinates(0.0, 1.0)
    coords = [tup, tup]
    a = b"foo"
    b = b"bar"
    words = [a, b]

    coord_array = FFIArray(coords, data_type=Coordinates)
    print(coord_array)
    word_array = FFIArray(words, c_char_p)
    print(word_array)
```

This works for e.g. `c_double`, but fails when I try it with `c_char_p`, with the following error (testing on Python 2.7.16 and 3.7.4, and NumPy 1.16.5, 1.17.2):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sth/dev/test/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_internal.py", line 600, in _dtype_from_pep3118
    dtype, align = __dtype_from_pep3118(stream, is_subdtype=False)
  File "/Users/sth/dev/test/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_internal.py", line 677, in __dtype_from_pep3118
    raise ValueError("Unknown PEP 3118 data type specifier %r" % stream.s)
ValueError: Unknown PEP 3118 data type specifier 'z'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so_example.py", line 42, in <module>
    word_array = FFIArray(words, c_char_p)
  File "so_example.py", line 19, in __init__
    array = np.ctypeslib.as_array((data_type * len(seq))(*seq))
  File "/Users/sth/dev/test/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/ctypeslib.py", line 523, in as_array
    return array(obj, copy=False)
ValueError: '<z' is not a valid PEP 3118 buffer format string
```

Is there a better way to do this? I'm also not wedded to using `numpy`, although it's useful for converting iterables of numeric types and `numpy` arrays to `_FFIArray` elsewhere.

Comment: It is interesting that the c_char_p is giving problems. Is the python string coming in UTF-8? Does the same error happen when working with `c_wchar_p`?

Comment: @nathan (On Python 2.7.16) The string's coming in as unicode. Switching to `c_wchar_p` has no effect…

Comment: No effect meaning the error remains?

Comment: @Nathan Sorry, yes. Same error.

Comment: That PEP error should have been patched according to [python error 10744](https://bugs.python.org/issue10744) but there is an interesting chain on the [Numpy github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11150) about ctype errors with older Python versions.

Comment: Hmm. Looks like the bug is still present on Python 3.7.4 / Numpy 1.17.2.

Comment: How do you expect the strings to be marshaled into the data array?  I can't reproduce the error you have, but got a different one.  Please make a [mcve].

Comment: Please also add how are you using the above code, and the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I've added an MCVE, and full stack trace.

Comment: @CristiFati Added a full runnable example and stack trace

Comment: @urschrei Can you give us a minimal code for reproducing the error. I failed to reproduce it. And test string that you are trying to test.

Comment: @urschrei `AttributeError: 'Coordinates' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'` :D getting this error..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

I didn't (yet) get to the bottom of *NumPy*'s error (so far I reached *_multiarray_umath* (*C*) sources, but I don't know how the functions from *_internal.py* are being called).

In the meantime, here's a variant that doesn't use *NumPy* (which is not needed in this case, but you mentioned you use it in other parts, so this probably fixes only part of your problem).

*code03.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import ctypes
import numpy as np


class FFIArray(ctypes.Structure):
    """
    Convert sequence of structs or types to C-compatible void array
    """

    _fields_ = [
        ("data", ctypes.c_void_p),
        ("len", ctypes.c_size_t)
    ]

    @classmethod
    def from_param(cls, seq, data_type):
        """  Allow implicit conversions """
        return seq if isinstance(seq, cls) else cls(seq, data_type)

    def __init__(self, seq, data_type):
        self.len = len(seq)
        self._data_type = data_type
        self._DataTypeArr = self._data_type * self.len
        self.data = ctypes.cast(self._DataTypeArr(*seq), ctypes.c_void_p)

    def __str__(self):
        ret = super().__str__()  # Python 3
        #ret = super(FFIArray, self).__str__()  # !!! Python 2 !!!
        ret += "\nType: {0:s}\nLength: {1:d}\nElement Type: {2:}\nElements:\n".format(
            self.__class__.__name__, self.len, self._data_type)
        arr_data = self._DataTypeArr.from_address(self.data)
        for idx, item in enumerate(arr_data):
            ret += "  {0:d}: {1:}\n".format(idx, item)
        return ret


class Coordinates(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("lat", ctypes.c_double),
        ("lon", ctypes.c_double)
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return "Latitude: {0:.3f}, Longitude: {1:.3f}".format(self.lat, self.lon)


def main():
    coord_list = [Coordinates(i+ 1, i * 2) for i in range(4)]
    s0 = b"foo"
    s1 = b"bar"
    word_list = [s0, s1]

    coord_array = FFIArray(coord_list, data_type=Coordinates)
    print(coord_array)
    word_array = FFIArray(word_list, ctypes.c_char_p)
    print(word_array)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    print("NumPy: {0:s}\n".format(np.version.version))
    main()
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Notes**:

- Fixed an error in *FFIArray.from_param* (missing *arg*)
- The *NumPy* usage from the initializer is pretty awkward:

  1. Create a *CTypes* array from the bytes value
  2. Create a *np* array (out of previous step result)
  3. Create a *CTypes* pointer (out of previous step result)
- Did some small refactors to the original code

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q058049957]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code03.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> NumPy: 1.16.2
>
> <__main__.FFIArray object at 0x0000019CFEB63648>
> Type: FFIArray
> Length: 4
> Element Type: <class '__main__.Coordinates'>
> Elements:
>   0: Latitude: 1.000, Longitude: 0.000
>   1: Latitude: 2.000, Longitude: 2.000
>   2: Latitude: 3.000, Longitude: 4.000
>   3: Latitude: 4.000, Longitude: 6.000
>
> <__main__.FFIArray object at 0x0000019CFEB637C8>
> Type: FFIArray
> Length: 2
> Element Type: <class 'ctypes.c_char_p'>
> Elements:
>   0: b'foo'
>   1: b'bar'
>
>
> Done.
> ```

---

#### Update *#0*

*PEP 3118* defines a standard for accessing (sharing) memory. Part of that are the format string specifiers used to do the conversions between a buffer contents and relevant data. Those are listed in [[Python.Docs]: PEP 3118 - Additions to the struct string-syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3118/#additions-to-the-struct-string-syntax) and extend the ones from [[Python 3.Docs]: struct - Format Characters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters). 
*ctypes* types have an (**!!!undocumented!!!**) *_type_* attribute which (I presume) is used when performing the conversion from / to *np*:

> ```py
> >>> import ctypes
> >>>
> >>> data_types = list()
> >>>
> >>> for attr_name in dir(ctypes):
> ...     attr = getattr(ctypes, attr_name, None)
> ...     if isinstance(attr, (type,)) and issubclass(attr, (ctypes._SimpleCData,)):
> ...         data_types.append((attr, attr_name))
> ...
> >>> for data_type, data_type_name in data_types:
> ...     print("{0:} ({1:}) - {2:}".format(data_type, data_type_name, getattr(data_type, "_type_", None)))
> ...
> <class 'ctypes.HRESULT'> (HRESULT) - l
> <class '_ctypes._SimpleCData'> (_SimpleCData) - None
> <class 'ctypes.c_bool'> (c_bool) - ?
> <class 'ctypes.c_byte'> (c_byte) - b
> <class 'ctypes.c_char'> (c_char) - c
> <class 'ctypes.c_char_p'> (c_char_p) - z
> <class 'ctypes.c_double'> (c_double) - d
> <class 'ctypes.c_float'> (c_float) - f
> <class 'ctypes.c_long'> (c_int) - l
> <class 'ctypes.c_short'> (c_int16) - h
> <class 'ctypes.c_long'> (c_int32) - l
> <class 'ctypes.c_longlong'> (c_int64) - q
> <class 'ctypes.c_byte'> (c_int8) - b
> <class 'ctypes.c_long'> (c_long) - l
> <class 'ctypes.c_double'> (c_longdouble) - d
> <class 'ctypes.c_longlong'> (c_longlong) - q
> <class 'ctypes.c_short'> (c_short) - h
> <class 'ctypes.c_ulonglong'> (c_size_t) - Q
> <class 'ctypes.c_longlong'> (c_ssize_t) - q
> <class 'ctypes.c_ubyte'> (c_ubyte) - B
> <class 'ctypes.c_ulong'> (c_uint) - L
> <class 'ctypes.c_ushort'> (c_uint16) - H
> <class 'ctypes.c_ulong'> (c_uint32) - L
> <class 'ctypes.c_ulonglong'> (c_uint64) - Q
> <class 'ctypes.c_ubyte'> (c_uint8) - B
> <class 'ctypes.c_ulong'> (c_ulong) - L
> <class 'ctypes.c_ulonglong'> (c_ulonglong) - Q
> <class 'ctypes.c_ushort'> (c_ushort) - H
> <class 'ctypes.c_void_p'> (c_void_p) - P
> <class 'ctypes.c_void_p'> (c_voidp) - P
> <class 'ctypes.c_wchar'> (c_wchar) - u
> <class 'ctypes.c_wchar_p'> (c_wchar_p) - Z
> <class 'ctypes.py_object'> (py_object) - O
> ```

As seen above, *c_char_p* and *c_whar_p*'s are not found or don't match the standard. At 1<sup>st</sup> glance, it seems it's a *ctypes* bug as it doesn't respect the standard, but I wouldn't rush into claiming this fact (and maybe submit a bug) before further investigations (especially because bugs have already been reported in this area: [[Python.Bugs]: ctypes arrays have incorrect buffer information (PEP-3118)](https://bugs.python.org/issue10744)).

Below is a variant that also handles *np* arrays.

*code04.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import ctypes
import numpy as np


class FFIArray(ctypes.Structure):
    """
    Convert sequence of structs or types to C-compatible void array
    """

    _fields_ = [
        ("data", ctypes.c_void_p),
        ("len", ctypes.c_size_t)
    ]

    _special_np_types_mapping = {
        ctypes.c_char_p: "S",
        ctypes.c_wchar_p: "U",
    }

    @classmethod
    def from_param(cls, seq, data_type=ctypes.c_void_p):
        """  Allow implicit conversions """
        return seq if isinstance(seq, cls) else cls(seq, data_type=data_type)

    def __init__(self, seq, data_type=ctypes.c_void_p):
        self.len = len(seq)
        self.__data_type = data_type  # Used just to hold the value passed to the initializer
        if isinstance(seq, np.ndarray):
            arr = np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(seq)
            self._data_type = arr._type_  # !!! data_type is ignored in this case !!!
            self._DataTypeArr = arr.__class__
            self.data = ctypes.cast(arr, ctypes.c_void_p)
        else:
            self._data_type = data_type
            self._DataTypeArr = self._data_type * self.len
            self.data = ctypes.cast(self._DataTypeArr(*seq), ctypes.c_void_p)

    def __str__(self):
        strings = [super().__str__()]  # Python 3
        #strings = [super(FFIArray, self).__str__()]  # !!! Python 2 (ugly) !!!
        strings.append("Type: {0:s}\nElement Type: {1:}{2:}\nElements ({3:d}):".format(
            self.__class__.__name__, self._data_type,
            "" if self._data_type == self.__data_type else " ({0:})".format(self.__data_type),
            self.len))
        arr_data = self._DataTypeArr.from_address(self.data)
        for idx, item in enumerate(arr_data):
            strings.append("  {0:d}: {1:}".format(idx, item))
        return "\n".join(strings) + "\n"

    def to_np(self):
        arr_data = self._DataTypeArr.from_address(self.data)
        if self._data_type in self._special_np_types_mapping:
            dtype = np.dtype(self._special_np_types_mapping[self._data_type] + str(max(len(item) for item in arr_data)))
            np_arr = np.empty(self.len, dtype=dtype)
            for idx, item in enumerate(arr_data):
                np_arr[idx] = item
            return np_arr
        else:
            return np.ctypeslib.as_array(arr_data)


class Coordinates(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("lat", ctypes.c_double),
        ("lon", ctypes.c_double)
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return "Latitude: {0:.3f}, Longitude: {1:.3f}".format(self.lat, self.lon)


def main():
    coord_list = [Coordinates(i + 1, i * 2) for i in range(4)]
    s0 = b"foo"
    s1 = b"bar (beyond all recognition)"  # To avoid having 2 equal strings
    word_list = [s0, s1]

    coord_array0 = FFIArray(coord_list, data_type=Coordinates)
    print(coord_array0)

    word_array0 = FFIArray(word_list, data_type=ctypes.c_char_p)
    print(word_array0)
    print("to_np: {0:}\n".format(word_array0.to_np()))

    np_array_src = np.array([0, -3.141593, 2.718282, -0.577, 0.618])
    float_array0 = FFIArray.from_param(np_array_src, data_type=None)
    print(float_array0)
    np_array_dst = float_array0.to_np()
    print("to_np: {0:}".format(np_array_dst))
    print("Equal np arrays: {0:}\n".format(all(np_array_src == np_array_dst)))

    empty_array0 = FFIArray.from_param([])
    print(empty_array0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    print("NumPy: {0:s}\n".format(np.version.version))
    main()
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```py
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q058049957]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code04.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> NumPy: 1.16.2
>
> <__main__.FFIArray object at 0x000002484A2265C8>
> Type: FFIArray
> Element Type: <class '__main__.Coordinates'>
> Elements (4):
>   0: Latitude: 1.000, Longitude: 0.000
>   1: Latitude: 2.000, Longitude: 2.000
>   2: Latitude: 3.000, Longitude: 4.000
>   3: Latitude: 4.000, Longitude: 6.000
>
> <__main__.FFIArray object at 0x000002484A2267C8>
> Type: FFIArray
> Element Type: <class 'ctypes.c_char_p'>
> Elements (2):
>   0: b'foo'
>   1: b'bar (beyond all recognition)'
>
> to_np: [b'foo' b'bar (beyond all recognition)']
>
> <__main__.FFIArray object at 0x000002484A2264C8>
> Type: FFIArray
> Element Type: <class 'ctypes.c_double'> (None)
> Elements (5):
>   0: 0.0
>   1: -3.141593
>   2: 2.718282
>   3: -0.577
>   4: 0.618
>
> to_np: [ 0.       -3.141593  2.718282 -0.577     0.618   ]
> Equal np arrays: True
>
> <__main__.FFIArray object at 0x000002484A226848>
> Type: FFIArray
> Element Type: <class 'ctypes.c_void_p'>
> Elements (0):
>
>
> Done.
> ```

Of course, this is one of the possibilities. Another one could involve (deprecated) [[SciPy.Docs]: numpy.char.array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.char.array.html#numpy.char.array) usage, but I didn't want to overcomplicate things (without a clear scenario).

---

#### Update *#1*

Added *FFIArray* to *np* array conversion (I'm not a *np* expert, so it might look cumbersome for one who is). Strings need special processing.
Didn't post a new code version (as the changes are not very significant), worked on previous one instead.