# Ctypes: "Debug assertion failed" (string != NULL) when passing pointer to dll function that uses sprintf

Tags: python, c++, pointers, pass-by-reference, ctypes

I'm trying to write a Python wrapper using Ctypes for a pre-written DLL file but keep struggling with a pointer issue.

Specifically, a simplified example of my C++ function that's been compiled into the DLL is:

```
double compute_result(double var1, double var2, char *output_message1, char *output_message2){
    // Computational steps are all here, e.g.
    double result = var1 + var2;

    // then an information message is passed to the output_message1 & 2 location
    sprintf(output_message1, "useful output message 1");
    sprintf(output_message2, "useful output message 2");

    return(result);
}
```

To wrap this using ctypes, I've tried to define the appropriate restype and argtype as follows. The C++ code doesn't specify a size for the output message pointer so I assume I don't have to using ctypes.

```
dll = ctypes.WinDLL("MyDLL.dll")
f = dll.compute_result
f.restype = c_double
f.argtypes = [c_double, c_double, POINTER(c_char), POINTER(c_char)]
```

I then try calling my code in Python using:

```
# Imports
import ctypes
from ctypes import c_double, c_char, POINTER, addressof, cast

# Input variables
var1 = 1.1
var2 = 2.2

# Create string buffers to hold output message, then convert address to a pointer to pass to dll function
size = 1024  # we know output messages will be shorter than 1024 characters
buf1 = ctypes.create_string_buffer(size)
buf2 = ctypes.create_string_buffer(size)

f(var1, var2, cast(addressof(buf1), POINTER(c_char)), cast(addressof(buf2), POINTER(c_char)))
```

Unfortunately, a dialog box error is displayed upon execution, saying:

```
"Debug Assertion Failed!"

Program: ...somepath_on_my_computer\python.exe
File: ...somepath_on_my_computer\sprintf.c
Line: 110

Expression: (string != NULL)
```

I understand that this implies some error with my pointers where sprintf is meant to write the output message too, but I can't see what exactly is wrong.
Is there a way to fix this please? Or am I handling pointers incorrectly? Thanks!

Comment: What's your *Python* version (full)?

Comment: Python 3.7.4 - the 32 bit version since the DLL is 32 bit.

Comment: What about `ctypes.CDLL("MyDLL.dll")`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the error message using CDLL in place of WinDLL is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Listing [[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

*buf1* and *buf2* (in underlying *C*) are seen as arrays, so **they are already addresses**.

Get rid of *addressof*, as it will trigger *Undefined Behavior* (check [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610333/calling-c-function-in-python-through-ctypes-but-function-returns-incorrect-valu/58611011#58611011)).

Try:

```py
f(var1, var2, cast(buf1, POINTER(c_char)), cast(buf2, POINTER(c_char)))
```

For more advanced example(s), check [[SO]: How can i cast a double pointer ctype to numpy array? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58781199/how-can-i-cast-a-double-pointer-ctype-to-numpy-array/58784385#58784385).

#### Edit *#0*

Adding code samples.

*dll00.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#if defined(_WIN32)
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API
#endif


#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

DLL00_EXPORT_API double dll00Func00(double var1, double var2, char *pMsg1, char *pMsg2);

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif


double dll00Func00(double var1, double var2, char *pMsg1, char *pMsg2) {
    double result = var1 + var2;
    sprintf(pMsg1, "useful output message 1");
    sprintf(pMsg2, "useful output message 2");
    return result;
}
```

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import ctypes as ct


DLL_NAME = "./dll00.dll"


def main():
    dll00 = ct.CDLL(DLL_NAME)
    dll00Func00 = dll00.dll00Func00
    dll00Func00.argtypes = [ct.c_double, ct.c_double, ct.POINTER(ct.c_char), ct.POINTER(ct.c_char)]
    dll00Func00.restype = ct.c_double

    v1 = 1.1
    v2 = 2.2
    size = 1024
    buf1 = ct.create_string_buffer(size)
    buf2 = ct.create_string_buffer(size)

    res = dll00Func00(v1, v2, ct.cast(buf1, ct.POINTER(ct.c_char)), ct.cast(buf2, ct.POINTER(ct.c_char)))
    print("{0:s} returned: {1:.3f}".format(dll00Func00.__name__, res))
    print(buf1.value, buf2.value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main()
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q058932240]> sopr.bat
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2017\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
> **********************************************************************
> ** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.9.17
> ** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
> **********************************************************************
> [vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
> dll00.c
>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /DDLL dll00.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll00.dll
> dll00.c
>    Creating library dll00.lib and object dll00.exp
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
> dll00.c
> dll00.dll
> dll00.exp
> dll00.lib
> dll00.obj
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> dll00Func00 returned: 3.300
> b'useful output message 1' b'useful output message 2'
>
> Done.
> ```

As a note, it also works when the *.dll* is build for debug.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion and the links. Unfortunately, even after removing `addressof`, the error remains with the same error message. I tried replacing POINTER(c_char) with c_char_p too but it makes no change. Are there any other obvious error / ways to debug this? Thanks