# What ctypes argument type to use for variably modified multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, ctypes, c99

Using *ctypes* in python I can freely pass an array to a *C* function using a pointer to its first element since an array decays to a pointer to its first element in *C*. So for the *C* function signature

```
void insert_sort(int A[], size_t length);
```

I can implement the following python wrapper.

```
import ctypes
from typing import List, Callable

def wrap_function(lib: ctypes.CDLL, name: str, restype: object, argtypes: List[object]) -> Callable:
    """Simplify wrapping ctypes functions"""
    func = lib.__getattr__(name)
    func.restype = restype
    func.argtypes = argtypes
    return func


lib = ctypes.CDLL("path/to/library.so")
insert_sort = wrap_function(lib, 'insert_sort', None, [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int), ctypes.c_size_t])
```

But *C* also allows one to have arrays of array and whats more variable sized arrays of arrays. For example the *C* function signature below demonstrates this.

```
void matrix_multiply(size_t n, int A[n][n], int B[n][n], int C[n][n]);
```

How would one wrap this function? To codify my question what goes in the blank below?

```
matrix_multiply = wrap_function(lib, 'matrix_multiply', None, [...What goes here...])
```

If the size of the arrays were known we could simply write

```
matrix_multiply = wrap_function(lib, 'matrix_multiply', None, [
    ctypes.c_size_t, ((ctypes.c_int * 4)*4), ((ctypes.c_int * 4)*4), ((ctypes.c_int * 4)*4)
])
```

for arrays of size 4. But what can we do when this number is unknown?

Comment: Show an *matrix\_multiply* example and how do you compile it.

Comment: @CristiFati I'm not sure what that has to do with the question. It could just be an empty function ```void matrix_multiply(size_t n, int A[n][n], int B[n][n], int C[n][n]){}```. The point is getting python to run it for arbitrary input arrays.

Comment: Good question indeed, I haven't ever thought about using vla with ctypes

Comment: @IvorDenham-Dyson: it does because I'm not sure what compiler would tolerate that (`void matrix_multiply(size_t n, int A[n][n], int B[n][n], int C[n][n]);`). Meaning that the presumption that you start from is invalid. You can pass multidimensional arrays, it's just a bit more complicated. However you can't pass *VLA*s. The arrays would have to be dimensioned.

Comment: @CristiFati Here's an online example https://onlinegdb.com/SkxXkTRipL of such a function.

Comment: *gcc* and *cl* don't like it. Anyhow, some examples for *2D* arrays: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58727931/how-to-pass-a-2d-array-from-python-to-c/58735157#58735157, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58781199/how-can-i-cast-a-double-pointer-ctype-to-numpy-array/58784385#58784385

Comment: @CristiFati Looking into it a bit it seems it to be fine with gcc and clang here https://godbolt.org/z/77wc3Z. There is also reference to this exact type of declaration here https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html, it appears to be a gnu extension. Thanks for the links

Comment: To clarify the above the gnu extension is that it allows this in C90 mode and C++. VLA is part of the C99 standard as far as I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on reverse engineering the ABI.  I compiled this test program to assembly...

```c
#include <stddef.h>
extern void matrix_multiply(size_t n, int A[n][n], int B[n][n], int C[n][n]);

extern int X[64][64];
extern int Y[64][64];
extern int Z[64][64];

void test(void)
{
  matrix_multiply(64, X, Y, Z);
}
```

... using GCC 9 on x86_64-linux, and I got this assembly language:

```
test:
    leaq    Z(%rip), %rcx
    leaq    Y(%rip), %rdx
    leaq    X(%rip), %rsi
    movl    $64, %edi
    jmp matrix_multiply@PLT
```

Based on this I conclude that a variably modified array parameter is passed as a pointer to its first element, so the appropriate ctypes declaration for `matrix_multiply` is

```py
c_int_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)
matrix_multiply = wrap_function(lib, 'matrix_multiply', None, [
    ctypes.c_size_t, c_int_p, c_int_p, c_int_p
])
```

Wrapper that takes NumPy arrays and/or memoryviews left as an exercise.